# Comaparing melting points of group 14 elements

Tags: periodic-trends, melting-point

I found that melting point of $\ce{Sn(232°C)}$ is less than $\ce {Pb (327.5°C)} $ but i also saw that the bond enthalpy of $\ce {Sn-Sn(187.1 ±0.3 kJ mol^{-1})}$ is more than $\ce{Pb-Pb  86.6 ±0.8 kJ mol^{-1}}$ in the gaseous state.

---

I do not have any data for their bond enthalpies in solid state. And since melting involves breaking of bonds in solid state to convert it to liquid state should bond enthalpy of $\ce {Sn-Sn}$ should be less than $\ce{Pb-Pb}$ in solid state? Why or why not? I would like to know if here melting points depend on some other factor. Source -https://www.webelements.com/lead/compound_properties.html I want to know about Bond enthalpy comparison of $\ce {Sn-Sn} $ and $\ce {Pb-Pb} $

Comment: The matter is qualitatively discussed here: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group4/properties.html

And indeed, there is a correlation between the trend of ionization energies and that of melting points (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page).

Comment: @The_Vinz the wiki page has the data but i dont understand how ionization energy would effect melting point. The significance of bond enthalpy is more I feel. However the first link I am not able to view

Comment: I guess that ionization energy might correlate with the strength of the metal bond (think of Fermi's metal bonding model, of atoms in a sea of electrons). Probably the ease with which a metal leaves its electrons might contribute to the strength of the metal bond

Comment: @The_Vinz what are the bond enthalpies of Sn-Sn and Pb-Pb in solid state is the question I am more interested in